# How to save the filtered document in mongodb c# from application?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

```
 var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("name", "CLOUDNAME");
 await coll.Find(filter).ForEachAsync(x => name = x["name"].ToString());
 MessageBox.Show(name);
```

It's not displaying the string name. 
Is there any way to display what i retrived?

Comment: Assuming you have declared and initialized `string name = "";`, your query simply returns no documents.

Comment: How can i save the retrieved document values in the program and display? @CodeCaster